# Glue Job failing due to Amazon S3 timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I've been working my way through the AWS glue tutorials (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/getting-started.html) and I'm now trying to configure my first job that aims to copy all data from a RDS table into a parquet file on S3.

I've successfully:

- created the S3 VPC endpoint
- created the glue RDS connection and crawler
- successfully added the RDS table meta data to the catalog.

To create the job I have:

- Selected 'add job' from the glue dashboard
- Given the job a name, assigned the same ROLE used for the RDS connection above (as it is assigned the AWSGlueServiceRole policy), selected 'A proposed script generated by AWS Glue' and left other fields default.
- Selected the desired RDS table from the catalog as the source
  for output selected 'create tables in your data target', using s3 as a data source, parquet as format, as as target selected a newly created output s3 folder - 'aws-glue-test-etl/data'
- After clicking NEXT I've left all field mappings as default.
- Save the job and edit the script

When I run the job with defaults I get the following log output:

```
--conf spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.connect.max-wait.ms=60000 --conf spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS=hdfs://ip-10-0-1-88.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020 --conf spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address=ip-10-0-1-88.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8032 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=18 --conf spark.executor.memory=5g --conf spark.executor.cores=4 --JOB_ID j_20380e2f5d565a53d8bd397904dd210cbca826f3825ae8ff6b5a23e8f7bca45d --JOB_RUN_ID jr_6d60e2930a43a06edf6b6e8307171e88bd754ac5f9e66f2eaf5373e570b61280 --scriptLocation s3://aws-glue-scripts-558091818291-eu-west-1/MarcFletcher/UpdateAccountsExport-py --job-bookmark-option job-bookmark-disable --job-language python --TempDir s3://aws-glue-temporary-558091818291-eu-west-1/MarcFletcher --JOB_NAME UpdateAccountsExport-py

YARN_RM_DNS=ip-10-0-1-88.eu-west-1.compute.internal

Detected region eu-west-1

JOB_NAME = UpdateAccountsExport-py

Specifying eu-west-1 while copying script.

S3 copy with region specified failed. Falling back to not specifying region.
```

And the following error output:

```
fatal error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='aws-glue-scripts-558091818291-eu-west-1.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /MarcFletcher/UpdateAccountsExport-py (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9b11afbf10>, 'Connection to aws-glue-scripts-558091818291-eu-west-1.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))

Error downloading script: fatal error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='aws-glue-scripts-558091818291-eu-west-1.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /MarcFletcher/UpdateAccountsExport-py (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe752548f10>, 'Connection to aws-glue-scripts-558091818291-eu-west-1.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))
```

I've reviewed the troubleshooting guide (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-troubleshooting-errors.html) but haven't found any potential solutions in there. The region being autoselected eu-west-1 is correct.

If anyone can point out where the job is going wrong that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue and will use my business support contract to try to get AWS engineers to provide an answer. I'll post an update here once we find a resolution.

Comment: @bradcosine Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: I might be late to the party, did anyone find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely security group  port blocking issue.

Check your AWS security group egress rule attached to glue connection, allows TCP on 443 port to all

Answer (score 1):

check in Redshift if Enhanced VPC routing is disabled .

Open Redshift cluster -> Properties/Network and security settings/edit and disable Enhanced VPC routing

AWS: "Enabling this option forces network traffic between your cluster and data repositories through a VPC, instead of the internet"

Answer (score 0):

It is important to have an S3 Endpoint in the subnet routing table.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/start-development-endpoint.html
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-glue-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/vpc-endpoints-s3.md

Despite this, I also found it necessary to specify the region when setting up the boto3 resource.

I couldn't find this, or related boto.config documented.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', 'ap-southeast-2')
file = s3.Object('bucket_name', 'file_key.txt')
file_contents = file.get()['Body'].read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Once your VPC endpoint is setup it is important to keep in mind that it [can only route traffic within a single AWS region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-troubleshooting-errors.html#error-s3-timeout). This means that the S3 bucket you try to access must be created in the same region as your AWS Glue related resources and in particular your S3 VPC Endpoint.

Comment: I've already mentioned in the OP that the S3 VPC endpoints have been created.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in your question. I have updated my answer rather than deleting it as the same-region part can still be useful to someone.